# Regex in Vue attribute v-validate

Tags: regex, validation, vue.js, vee-validate

I would like to allow dash/hyphen in the name field

```
<input v-model="$parent.teacher.firstName" v-validate="'required|alpha|min:2'"
                           placeholder="Eva" class="bw" type="text" name="firstname"
                           autocomplete="teacher-firstname"/>
```

How can I accomplish it? I tried to add a regex like e.g. '^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$' in v-validate but nothing happens

Comment: Then replace `alpha` with [`alpha_dash`](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#alpha-dash).

Answer (score 4):

You could [create a custom rule](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html#creating-a-custom-rule)

Something like this:

```js
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';

Validator.extend('name', {
  getMessage: field => 'The ' + field + ' value is not a valid name.',
  validate: value => value.test(/^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$/)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider changing `alpha` with [`alpha_dash`](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#alpha-dash).

You may set the custom regex using `v-validate="{ required: true, regex: /^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$/i, min: 2 }"`:

```
<input v-model="$parent.teacher.firstName"
  v-validate="{ required: true, regex: /^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$/i, min: 2 }" 
  placeholder="Eva" class="bw" type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="teacher-firstname">
```

See the [relevant documentation](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#regex).